# None of these file exist: the path

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I try to running a react native app on an android emulator i got this error:

```html
None of these files exist:
  * src\components\spacer\spacer.component(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * src\components\spacer\spacer.component\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
   5 | import { SvgXml } from "react-native-svg";
   6 |
>  7 | import Spacer from "../../../components/spacer/spacer.component";
     |                     ^
   8 | import star from "../../../../assets/star";
   9 | import open from "../../../../assets/open";
  10 |
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:152:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:264:43)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:170:21)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:466:33)
    at processModule (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:232:31)
    at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:221:3)
    at async traverseDependencies (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:147:7)
    at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\DeltaCalculator.js:263:42)
    at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\DeltaCalculator.js:90:16)
    at async DeltaBundler.getDelta (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler.js:74:12)
    at async IncrementalBundler.updateGraph (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\IncrementalBundler.js:245:19)
    at async Server._explodedSourceMapForURL (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1166:23)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Server._symbolicate (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1088:26)
    at async Server._processRequest (C:\Users\rubyh\Documents\project\MealsToGo\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:458:7)
```

src/components/spacer/spacer.component.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

const TopSmall = styled.View`
  margin-top: ${(props) => props.theme.space[1]};
`;

const TopMedium = styled.View`
  margin-top: ${(props) => props.theme.space[2]};
`;

const TopLarge = styled.View`
  margin-top: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
`;

const LeftSmall = styled.View`
  margin-left: ${(props) => props.theme.space[1]};
`;

const LeftMedium = styled.View`
  margin-left: ${(props) => props.theme.space[2]};
`;

const LeftLarge = styled.View`
  margin-left: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
`;

export const Spacer = ({ variant }) => {
  if (variant === "top.medium") {
    return <TopMedium />;
  }
  if (variant === "top.large") {
    return <TopLarge />;
  }
  if (variant === "left.small") {
    return <LeftSmall />;
  }
  if (variant === "left.medium") {
    return <LeftMedium />;
  }
  if (variant === "left.large") {
    return <LeftLarge />;
  }
  return <TopSmall />;
};
```

restaurant-info-card.component.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import { Text, Image, View } from "react-native";
import { Card } from "react-native-paper";
import { SvgXml } from "react-native-svg";

import { Spacer } from "../../../components/spacer/spacer.component";
import star from "../../../../assets/star";
import open from "../../../../assets/open";

const RestaurantCard = styled(Card)`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.bg.primary};
`;

const RestaurantCardCover = styled(Card.Cover)`
  padding: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.bg.primary};
`;

const Address = styled(Text)`
  font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.fonts.body};
  font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fontSizes.caption};
`;

const Title = styled(Text)`
  font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.fonts.heading};
  font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fontSizes.body};
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.ui.primary};
`;

const Info = styled.View`
  padding: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
`;

const Rating = styled.View`
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: ${(props) => props.theme.space[2]};
  padding-bottom: ${(props) => props.theme.space[2]};
`;

const Section = styled.View`
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
`;

const SectionEnd = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
`;

export const RestaurantInfoCard = ({ restaurant = {} }) => {
  const {
    name = "Some Restaurant",
    icon = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/lodging-71.png",
    photos = [
      "https://www.foodiesfeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/top-view-for-box-of-2-burgers-home-made-600x899.jpg",
    ],
    address = "100 some random street",
    isOpenNow = true,
    rating = 4,
    isClosedTemporarily = true,
  } = restaurant;

  const ratingArray = Array.from(new Array(Math.floor(rating)));

  return (
    <RestaurantCard elevation={5}>
      <RestaurantCardCover key={name} source={{ uri: photos[0] }} />
      <Info>
        <Title>{name}</Title>
        <Section>
          <Rating>
            {ratingArray.map(() => (
              <SvgXml xml={star} width={20} height={20} />
            ))}
          </Rating>
          <SectionEnd>
            {isClosedTemporarily && (
              <Text variant="label" style={{ color: "red" }}>
                CLOSED TEMPORARILY
              </Text>
            )}
            <Spacer variant="left.large" />
            {isOpenNow && <SvgXml xml={open} width={20} height={20} />}
            <Spacer variant="left.large" />
            <Image style={{ width: 15, height: 15 }} source={{ uri: icon }} />
          </SectionEnd>
        </Section>
        <Address>{address}</Address>
      </Info>
    </RestaurantCard>
  );
};
```

react: 18.1.0
react-native: 0.70.5

```js
assets
 ┣ adaptive-icon.png
 ┣ favicon.png
 ┣ icon.png
 ┣ open.js
 ┣ splash.png
 ┗ star.js
 node_modules
 src
 ┣ components
 ┃ ┗ spacer
 ┃ ┃ ┗ spacer.component.js
 ┣ features
 ┃ ┗ restaurants
 ┃ ┃ ┣ components
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ restaurant-info-card-component.js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ screens
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ restaurant.screen.js
 ┣ infrastructure
 ┃ ┗ theme
 ┃ ┃ ┣ colors.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ fonts.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ index.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ sizes.js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ spacing.js
.eslintrc.js
.gitignore
App.js
app.json
babel.config.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

Please help me I have try to googling for almost a week for this error already but no thing changed please help

Comment: Your path is showing outside of the project folder, if the file, you're accessing the paths from are in the root folder of the project. This must be restricted for the react app to access data from outside of its scope. Could you try to use ../ instead of ../../../../ before your path. Or tell us where how your file-tree looks like?

Comment: I have already add a file-tree.

Comment: Okay, your edit was 1 hour ago, whereas my comment was 2 hours ago. So the file tree hadn't exists to that time. Okay it seems like, that the ../ are correct in the amount and this actually should work. However as you have very deeply structured file tree, I would suggest you to use the module `babel-plugin-module-resolver` where you can set e.g. expose: 'root' as "src" : './application' and your import would then look like `import { Spacer } from "root/assets/spacer/spacer.component";`. So basically the part "root" would be translated to your root folder. Does that sound like a plan?

Comment: But how to do it? Like what I need to change in my code. Sorry for that but I am a complete beginner trying to learn code so yeah.

Comment: Sorry for the short description, as you know the comments have a character limit. Will post an answer for that, if it solves your issue and suits your approach, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I would use the `babel-plugin-module-resolver`in a project with such a deep file tree.

To do so, you can use these steps, as described at the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver):

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver`

Specify the plugin in your .babelrc with the custom root or alias. Here's an example:

```json
    {
      "plugins": [
        ["module-resolver", {
          "root": ["./src"],
          "alias": {
            "test": "./test",
            "underscore": "lodash"
          }
        }]
      ]
    }
```

**.babelrc.js** version Specify the plugin in your .babelrc.js file with the custom root or alias. Here's an example:

```js
const plugins = [
  [
    require.resolve('babel-plugin-module-resolver'),
    {
      root: ["."],
      alias: {
        "src": "./src"
      }
    }
  ]
];
```

Now you can use this:

```js
import star from "root/assets/star";
```

over this:

```js
import star from "../../../../assets/star";
```

Comment: Unable to resolve "root/assets/spacer/spacer.component" from "src\features\restaurants\components\restaurant-info-card-component.js" I got this error when it bundling

Comment: You may have to clean your project and npm cache before starting.